# How can i create a contingency table in R?

Tags: r

i want to create following contingency table in R.

```
          Cancer    Don't_Have_Cancer

 Smoke     18        9
 Don't_Smoke 5       24
```

I am a beginner in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should give a reproducible example. Here some data:

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(Smoker=sample(c('Smoke','No_Smoke'),20,rep=TRUE),
           CANCER=sample(c('Cancer','NO_Cancer'),20,rep=TRUE))
```

Then using `table` you can get your contingency table:

```
table(dat$Smoker,dat$CANCER)
         Cancer NO_Cancer
  No_Smoke      7         4
  Smoke         5         4
```

For more information see `?table`

Description

> table uses the cross-classifying factors to build a **contingency table**
>   of the counts at each combination of factor levels.

Comment: How can i use my own data in the contingency table ?

Comment: What is the question? do you mean how can you use `table` function with your data?

Comment: that is, how can i create contingency table with my given data given on the question?